# Parsing JSON that is a few levels deep in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

The json that is being forwarded from my webservice looks like this:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "T": "MR",
        "GUID": "8DDF0A79-A28E-4A1E-A0C4-4E613DA8CEF4",
        "I#": "8204035318089",
        "AGE": "31",
        "FN": "ELAB APP SPEED",
        "DOB": "1982-04-03",
        "SEX": "M",
        "SN": "TESTING",
        "U#": "VH02094770",
        "TYPE": "P",
        "UPD": "2014-03-01T10:26:00.000"
    },
    {
        "T": "MR",
        "GUID": "8C3918B0-6746-408A-83CF-742B1C9F8EF1",
        "I#": "NA",
        "AGE": "31",
        "FN": "ELAB MON",
        "SEX": "M",
        "SN": "TESTING",
        "U#": "VH02096387",
        "TYPE": "P",
        "UPD": "2014-03-03T08:21:00.000"
    },
    {
        "T": "MRS",
        "GUID": "0D19BC4A-E035-4420-81D5-20082D793DE3",
        "I#": "7208070301082",
        "AGE": "41",
        "FN": "ESTHER",
        "DOB": "1972-08-07",
        "SEX": "F",
        "SN": "RAITPORT",
        "U#": "VH01536667",
        "TYPE": "P",
        "UPD": "2014-03-02T21:05:00.000"
    }
],
"ok": "true"
}
```

So as you can see on the first level we have 'results' and 'ok', where 'results' is an array object. So, how would I parse this in such a way that I can iterate through the 'results' array and select, for instance, each 'FN' element (firstname) and print it out?

Lets say that 'data' is the data that was retrieved from the web service. I would then parse it to an NSDictionary like so:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
```

I can then access the 'results' element like so:

```
[json objectForKey:@"results"]
```

but this is where I get stuck... what do I save 'results' as? And how to do I itterate through results then and access the child elements e.g. 'FN', 'SN', 'AGE' etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
[json objectForKey:@"results"]
```

Will return a `NSArray` that will contain a `NSDictionary` for every element on it, and that dictioary will have "T", "GUID", etc... as keys.

So, you can do for example:

```
NSArray *myArray = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDicitonary *myDict = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NString *string = [mydict objectforKey:"T"];
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use keyed/indexed subscripting: `json[@"results"]` and `myArray[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Antonio's answer is correct, moreover, you can also use KVC, for instance to get a `NSArray*` of all the first names:

```
[json valueForKeyPath:@"results.FN"];
```

Or a `NSNumber*` containing the average age:

```
[json valueForKeyPath:@"results.@avg.AGE"];
```